# Detect what is the path in SVG file when click

Tags: javascript, svg

I'm working with SVG file. I was embed SVG file through object tag html.

Like this:

```
<object id="map" type="image/svg+xml" data="the-file-has-same-domain"></object>
```

How can I detect what area when I clicked by Javascript or any library support for this.

Thanks!!!

Comment: You're looking to capture what svg element was clicked on on this externally referenced svg file?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since your file is on the same domain (if we trust your fake-name), then you can simply access its document, and attach listeners from your main page:

```js
// wait for your <object> is loaded
document.getElementById('map').onload = e => {
  const doc = map.getSVGDocument(); // that's the inner document
  doc.addEventListener('click', your_handler);
};
```

Unfortunately StackSnippet's null-origined iframes don't allow access to **any** inner document, so [here is a jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qtp2fymz/).

Answer (score 0):

You can do this if you use inline svg directly.
Then you can add a handler onClick from javascript and fetch the path details using event.target in function

```
<svg version="1.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 3400 2700" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" onClick="goHome();">
  <g id="layer101">
    <path d="M1410 2283 c-162 -225 -328 -455 -370 -513 -422 -579 -473 -654 -486 -715 -7 -33 -50 -247 -94 -475 -44 -228 -88 -448 -96 -488 -9 -40 -14 -75 -11 -78 2 -3 87 85 188 196 165 180 189 202 231 215 25 7 129 34 230 60 100 26 184 48 185 49 4 4 43 197 43 212 0 10 -7 13 -22 9 -13 -3 -106 -25 -208 -49 -102 -25 -201 -47 -221 -51 l-37 -7 8 42 c4 23 12 45 16 49 5 4 114 32 243 62 129 30 240 59 246 66 10 10 30 132 22 139 -1 2 -110 -24 -241 -57 -131 -33 -240 -58 -242 -56 -6 6 13 98 22 107 5 4 135 40 289 80 239 61 284 75 307 98 14 15 83 90 153 167 70 77 132 140 139 140 7 0 70 -63 141 -140 70 -77 137 -150 150 -163 17 -19 81 -39 310 -97 159 -41 292 -78 296 -82 8 -9 29 -106 24 -111 -1 -2 -112 24 -245 58 -134 33 -245 58 -248 56 -6 -7 16 -128 25 -136 5 -4 112 -30 238 -59 127 -29 237 -54 246 -57 11 -3 20 -23 27 -57 6 -28 9 -53 8 -54 -1 -1 -38 7 -81 17 -274 66 -379 90 -395 90 -16 0 -16 -6 3 -102 11 -57 21 -104 22 -106 1 -1 96 -27 211 -57 115 -31 220 -60 234 -66 14 -6 104 -101 200 -211 95 -111 175 -197 177 -192 1 5 -40 249 -91 542 l-94 532 -145 203 c-220 309 -446 627 -732 1030 -143 201 -265 366 -271 367 -6 0 -143 -183 -304 -407z m10 -819 l-91 -161 -209 -52 c-115 -29 -214 -51 -219 -49 -6 1 32 55 84 118 l95 115 213 101 c116 55 213 98 215 94 1 -3 -38 -78 -88 -166z m691 77 l214 -99 102 -123 c56 -68 100 -125 99 -127 -4 -3 -435 106 -447 114 -4 2 -37 59 -74 126 -38 68 -79 142 -93 166 -13 23 -22 42 -20 42 2 0 101 -44 219 -99z"/>
    <path d="M1126 2474 c-198 -79 -361 -146 -363 -147 -2 -3 -70 -410 -133 -805 -12 -73 -20 -137 -18 -143 2 -6 26 23 54 63 27 40 224 320 437 622 213 302 386 550 385 551 -2 2 -165 -62 -362 -141z"/>
    <path d="M1982 2549 c25 -35 159 -230 298 -434 139 -203 283 -413 319 -465 37 -52 93 -134 125 -182 59 -87 83 -109 73 -65 -5 20 -50 263 -138 747 -17 91 -36 170 -42 176 -9 8 -571 246 -661 280 -14 6 -7 -10 26 -57z"/>
    <path d="M1679 1291 c-8 -11 -71 -80 -141 -153 l-127 -134 -95 -439 c-52 -242 -92 -442 -90 -445 6 -5 38 28 218 223 l99 107 154 0 c85 0 163 -4 173 -10 10 -5 78 -79 151 -162 73 -84 136 -157 140 -162 18 -21 18 4 -2 85 -11 46 -58 248 -105 448 l-84 364 -87 96 c-108 121 -183 201 -187 201 -2 0 -10 -9 -17 -19z m96 -488 c33 -102 59 -189 57 -192 -2 -6 -244 -2 -251 4 -5 6 120 375 127 375 4 0 34 -84 67 -187z"/>
    </g>
  </svg>

goHome = function(ev) {
  //path details
  console.log(ev.target);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

To get mouse coordinates when clicked on an element use `e.clientX` and `e.clientY`

```js
document.querySelector('#map').addEventListener('click', function (e) {
  console.log('X coords: ' + e.clientX + ', Y coords: ' + e.clientY);
});
```

```css
#map {
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<object id="map" type="image/svg+xml" data="the-file-has-same-domain"></object>
```